# Work with Excel table in ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, ms-office

I have MS Word form with some fields and to these fields I can insert Excel tables.

Now I have to convert this Word form into web application form, web app is written in ASP.NET.

I there some way to make possible inserting Excel tables using web app(copy-paste from Excel, keep formatting, not need formulas - only data), storing them in DB and show back in web app?

Thanks a lot

Comment: When you say *excel tables* do you mean you need to display a grid and store values from it into a database column or do you just want to display something like `Name  [textbox to input name]` etc and you were using tables in MS Word to organize that before?

Comment: yes i mean grid, but with formatting like it is in Excel sheet, i select foramted table with values from excel sheet->paste it to some control in web app(keep formatting and values)-> store it in DB(binary or something)->show in some control as formated table again in web app

Comment: Would you like to also be able to edit that data when you show it again, or just display it with the same formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using MS SQL Server?

If you can get those tables into an Excel file, you can [use SQL Server Management Studio's Import/Export Wizard to import data into a table from an Excel file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx).

Comment: thanks for tip but i need to insert excel tables as objects in web app

Comment: First of all, you're not inserting into a web app.  You're inserting into a database, right?  Database stores all sorts of data types, but "object" is not one of them.

Comment: yes, but I can store binary objects as BLOB in MS SQL, so if i can somehow work with Excel table in web app(when i copy excel table from excel sheet and paste it to text box in web app, i have tab delimited text, but not table formatting...so i need another way) maybe i can store it in DB as binary data

Comment: That's probably the least efficient way of storing data.